# Subsequent MySQL Queries Screwing Up Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

**EDIT** **Problem Solved**

So I have ran into an irritating problem while trying to implement very basic MySQL Query functionality with PHP on a website I am creating.

I am pretty new to PHP / HTML so this might be a very simple solution, but I Googled around and couldn't find anything.

So in my database, I have a Table called Teams that contains the fields "name" and "continent" which are both char (20) fields.

On this webpage, I have a table showing all the names of the teams in a certain continent. (this functionality is currently working fine)

The problem lies within a section under this table which allows the user to enter the current name of a team they wish to update (change team name / continent) and enter a new name for the team or change its continent.

The first field (current name) is required so that the SQL UPDATE knows which record to update, and the other two fields (new name, and new continent) are optional.

The new name field is a text field, and the new continent field is a dropdown menu.

There is a Submit button under these that will update the record.

Currently, changing the name of the team works perfectly, but whenever I try to update the continent of a team, it does not change the continent, but instead changes the name of the team to "", or a blank name basically.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="alter-teams">
    Update Team:
    <div>
        Enter the current name of the team you want to update in the first box.
        <br />
        Enter the new name and / or select the new continent.
        <form method="post">
            Current Team Name: <input type="text" name="teamname" required="" />
            <br />
            New Team Name: <input type="text" name="newteamname" r />
            <br />
            New Continent: <select name="continent" />
            <option value="Asia" selected="">Asia</option>
            <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="North America">North America</option>
            <option value="South America">South America</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="updateteam" value="Update Team" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updateteam']))
    {
        //set up table variablew
        $table = mysql_select_db("cs275_anzianoa", $DBCNX);
        if(!$table){
            echo 'Table Fail';
        }

        //get input from HTML form(s)
        $teamname = $_POST['teamname'];
        $newteamname = $_POST['newteamname'];
        $continent = $_POST['continent'];

        //perform UPDATE function
        if(isset($newteamname))
        {
            $query = 
            "UPDATE Teams SET name = '$newteamname' WHERE name = '$teamname'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(!$result){
                echo 'Update Query Fail' . mysql_error();
            }
        }


        if(isset($continent))
        {
            $query =
            "UPDATE Teams SET continent = '$continent' WHERE name = '$teamname'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo 'Update Query Fail' . mysql_error();
            }
        }

        //refresh page      
        echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
    }
?>
```

NOTE: The default value for the dropdown is Asia because this webpage currently shows all teams in Asia.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do the 'continent' update first then change the teamname. If both are changed at once, since the 'team name' is the lookup key, then it must be the last item to be changed.

Comment: **EDIT** I fixed it, was using wrong variable. Thanks!

Ah, I see. That makes sense. 

However, it is still wiping the name completely when I don't enter a name in the "New Team Name" field. I even changed the if statement before the teamname continent to


`if($newteamname !== '')`


to check if the string was empty because I think it is just overwriting it with whatever is in that field (nothing).

Comment: Glad you fixed it! If you think someone else would benefit from your solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. If it was just a typo and won't help others, please delete your question. Leaving a question open and unanswered is an indication that it's unsolved and other users (like me) will end up opening pages to solve problems that no longer exist.

Comment: Done and done, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Ryan Vincent, I was able to fix my issue.

The problem lied within the order in which I was performing my queries. I was changing the name first, then trying to change the continent, however the change to continent was dependent on the name of the team. So after the first query fired, the second query was having issues changing the right team.

Also, my

```
if(isset($newteamname))
```

was not working as intended because it does not return NULL if it is an empty string. So if I left the second box empty, it would overwrite the teamname with an empty string.

Therefore, I changed it to

```
if($newteamname !== '')
```

Below is the full, working code :)

```
<!-- Update Team -->
<div class="alter-teams">
    Update Team:
    <div>
        Enter the current name of the team you want to update in the first box.
        <br />
        Enter the new name and / or select the new continent.
        <form method="post">
            Current Team Name: <input type="text" name="teamname" required="" />
            <br />
            New Team Name: <input type="text" name="newteamname" r />
            <br />
            New Continent: <select name="continent" />
            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="North America" selected="">North America</option>
            <option value="South America">South America</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="updateteam" value="Update Team" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updateteam']))
    {
        //set up table variable
        $table = mysql_select_db("cs275_anzianoa", $DBCNX);
        if(!$table){
            echo 'Table Fail';
        }

        //get input from HTML form(s)
        $teamname = $_POST['teamname'];
        $newteamname = $_POST['newteamname'];
        $continent = $_POST['continent'];

        //perform UPDATE function
        if(isset($continent))
        {
            $query =
            "UPDATE Teams SET continent = '$continent' WHERE name = '$teamname'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo 'Update Query Fail' . mysql_error();
            }
        }

        if($newteamname !== '')
        {
            $query = 
            "UPDATE Teams SET name = '$newteamname' WHERE name = '$teamname'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(!$result){
                echo 'Update Query Fail' . mysql_error();
            }
        }


        //refresh page      
        echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
    }
?>
```